# Avoiding duplicate code while handling exception

Tags: python, oop, dry, anonymous-function, code-duplication

For my application, I need to use two slightly different algorithms for persisting an entity:

```
def persistRandomAlias(self, alias):
    self.em.persist(alias)
    try:
        self.em.flush()
    except DBALException as e:
        if e.previous.code != 23000:
            raise e
        self.reloadEM()

        self.persistRandomAlias(alias)



def persistCustomAlias(self, alias):
    self.em.persist(alias)
    try:
        self.em.flush()
    except DBALException as e:
        if e.previous.code != 23000:
            raise e
        self.reloadEM()

        existing = self.findByNaturalKey(alias.name)
        if existing != alias:
            raise DuplicateNameException('The requested name is already taken', e)
```

The difference between them is in part of the code responsible for exception handling. I thought about putting the common code in one method, with remaining operations passed in a function that would accept exception object, like this:

```
def persistAlias(self, alias, exHandler):
    self.em.persist(alias)
    try:
        self.em.flush()
    except DBALException as e:
        if e.previous.code != 23000:
            raise e
        self.reloadEM()

        exHandler(e)

def persistRandomAlias(self, alias):
    self.persistAlias(alias, lambda e: self.persistRandomAlias(alias))            

def persistCustomAlias(self, alias):
    def exHandler(e):
        existing = self.findByNaturalKey(alias.name)
        if existing != alias:
            raise DuplicateNameException('The requested name is already taken', e)

    self.persistAlias(alias, exHandler)
```

However, I'm not sure if it is correct to pass an unused argument to a function.

I have also thought about refactoring common code into an abstract method object class, like this:

```
def execute(self):
    self.em.persist(alias)
    try:
        self.em.flush()
    except DBALException as e:
        if e.previous.code != 23000:
            raise e
        self.reloadEM()
        self.e = e

        self.handleE()
```

handleE() would be implemented in subclasses of the class implementing execute() method, and it could access exception object, or not, depending on implementation.

Should I choose one of these ideas for dealing with code duplication? Which one is better? Do you suggest a better solution?

Comment: Consider asking on CodeReview. This is opinion-based question and is likely to be closed.

Comment: @BartoszKP, I already did: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101651/avoiding-code-repetition-while-handling-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Which line would raise an exception? It is better practice to isolate the line that will cause an exception in your try statement. You could do:

```
def persistAlias(self, alias, is_custom=False):
    try:
        self.em.persist(alias)
        self.em.flush()
    except DBALException as e:
        if e.previous.code != 23000:
            raise e
        self.reloadEM()

        if is_custom:
            existing = self.findByNaturalKey(alias.name)
            if existing != alias:
                raise DuplicateNameException(
                    'The requested name is already taken', e)
        else:
            self.persistAlias(alias)
```

Comment: It's not visible in the code I provided, but there are reasons for which I wouldn't pick your suggestion.

First, the actual type of alias depends on user providing custom name value, or leaving it blank. The test for is_custom inside persistAlias method would be redundant, since it would be performed by the code responsible for both creating alias object and calling persist method.

Second thing is that the requested alias type (custom vs. random) will not change when running persistAlias() again as a response to the exception, which would also make the test redundant.

Comment: As for the line causing exception: its self.em.flush(). I'll edit the question to fix it.